# Websphere trust authentication interceptor

Tags: java, websphere

I've spent some time researching how to automate a login between two web applications which I am hosting on the same Websphere app server instance.

Ie. I have web app a. I want to show webapp b in an iframe inside webapp a but I do not want my user to login when the iframe shows. The crentials for both applications are the same so I want an auto login. They both require a jsessionid cookie.

I read about the trust authentication interceptor that comes with was. Can anyone verify that it can be used to achieve an automatic login between web applications?

How would it work in my situation.

I am using was 6.1.

Thanks

Comment: You need single sign on solution. TAI - just interceptor when you can write custom logic (call external authentication provider etc)

Comment: TAI would accomplish the login, however Anton is right Single Sign On is the righ way, look at LTPA2

Comment: I just had a quick look at LTPA. Looks like it is for single sign onto the admin console between Websphere instances. Can it be used for single sign in between applications on the same instance?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307297/using-a-trust-association-interceptor-tai-to-obtain-a-ltpa2-token